# how to fix localStorage is not defined in react js and how to set and get Item back

Tags: javascript, reactjs

why localStorage is not defined

```js
  const [bookmark, setBookmark] = useState([]);
  const { showBookmark, setShowBookmark } = useContext(Context);

  const addToBookmark = (id) => {
    if (!bookmark.includes(id)) setBookmark(bookmark.concat(id));
  };

  const removeBookmark = (id) => {
    let index = bookmark.indexOf(id);
    let temp = [...bookmark.slice(0, index), ...bookmark.slice(index + 1)];
    setBookmark(temp);
  };
  let findBookmark = data1.ayat.filter((e) => bookmark.includes(e.nomor));

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(findBookmark));
  }, [findBookmark]);

  findBookmark = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list')) || '[]';
```

So, I want to make bookmark feature in my project where I get the data from `data1`. When I click `addBookmark` it will save data as per `id` to `localStorage` and it works, but when I use `getItem` from localStorage errors appear:

```
ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
```

and then `findBookmark.map()`

Comment: are u using server side rendering?

Comment: i use client side

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are seeing is because `localStorage`, which is an alias for `window.localStorage`, is not defined on the server side. A server renders your components, so when that happens, and it tries to access `localStorage` it can't find it. You'll have to wait until the browser renders it in order to use `localStorage`.

`localStorage` will have the value (window object) after the `useEffect()` runs. You can test it using the code snippet below inside the `useEffect()` hook.

```js
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  console.log('You are on the browser')
  // ️ can use localStorage here
} else {
  console.log('You are on the server')
  // ️ can't use localStorage
}
```

For further clarifications you can visit this link:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/19911

Answer (score -2):

Please use `window.localStorage` or `globalThis.localStorage`

Comment: Accessing `localStorage` should work on the frontend. This function is in fact a global already. Try to open the browsers' console and type in `localStorage`, you'll see that you are able to access the properties from this class.

Comment: Please justify yourself. Why should he use one instead of another?

Comment: Example If you are using inside a web worker, or any other areas you will get undefined when accessing localStorage, But you dont need if you are using in the browser, please try it and see..